# Multiple imputation of time variables -- which step to impute?

Tags: survival, missing-data, multiple-imputation

Lets assume I have a survival analysis study with an exposure, two covariates, and two time related variables. Say date of diagnosis and date of death. Combined, the two time related variables will be used to make a survival time variable: `t = date of death - date of diagnosis` .

The problem is that some of those date variables are missing. That should be addressable by multiple imputation, but I'm not sure *which* part I should be imputing - the dates used to make t, or t itself, based on the values of the other covariates.

My concern with using the date is the influence that will have on the imputed values - that if there's a small number of people diagnosed on say May 8th that they'll have a hugely disproportionate influence on the imputed values vs. other demographic characteristics for someone diagnosed May 8th but missing their outcome date. If it helps, the outcome in question isn't seasonal or time-related, so time *shouldn't* - at least to my mind - have a heavy influence.

Comment: Mysterious down-voter - any reason why? Suggestions for improvement?

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense to impute the individual times unless you think there are secular trends in the data set (e.g. lots of people being diagnosed/dying in a predictable way). If you must impute (which I generally don't like doing) I don't see how you can rationalize doing anything other than imputing t.

Comment: White and Royston (Statist.Med., 2009) suggest to include in the imputation model the Nelson-Aalen estimate of the cumulative hazard (`H(t)`) **instead of** `log(t)` (or `t`). What would you do in the case described by @EpiGrad? Would you include `H(t)`, `d` (censoring indicator) **and** `t` (or `log(t)`) in your imputation model (plus additional relevant variables, of course) so that you can impute the values of `t`?

Comment: @EpiGrad, have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @andrea Yes and no. For my particular problem, it appears I can make a compelling argument that everything is interval censored, rather than missing. So I more dodged the problem.

Comment: @andrea Going through old questions I haven't accepted answers to, and happened across this one. Any inclination to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Before turning that comment into an answer... I was thinking, `t` is likely to be a censored r.v., right? I think this is a major issue when it comes to imputing `t` using, for example, MICE. But what about quantile imputation? Look for example at this: http://www.stata.com/meeting/sweden11/abstracts/bottai_nordic11.pdf if you don't have administrative truncation of the follow-up, this might be a solution. Imputation of missing values using laplace regression can take care of the fact that `t` is (most likely very skewed and) censored. @EpiGrad